# EXCEL Dynamic Drop Down List with an Input

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to create a drop down list to select values that with a specific input.

For example, if I have a table below.

[image]

And then, I would like to have a drop down list to select dates by the name. Like the one below.

[image]

I feel like it can be done by using array formula and if function, something like `IF(A2:A7=A,B2:B7)`. It seems array formula cannot be used in a drop down list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Few steps involved but not to hard:

**Sorted column A**

[image]

- Create new named range, e.g.:  DropList`

  ```
  =INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!$D$2,Sheet1!$A:$A;0)+COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet1!$D$2)-1)
  ```
- Insert your dropdown validation list and reference the named range

  ```
  =DropList
  ```

**Unsorted column A**

[image]

- You'll need a helper column for this.
- In cell `H1` create a formula:

  ```
  =IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,3,($A$2:$A$7=$D$2)*($B$2:$B$7),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,"<>"&$D$2)+ROW()),"")
  ```
- Drag the formula down to `H7`
- Go to name manager and create a new named range, e.g.: `DropList`

  ```
  =Sheet1!$H$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$H:$H,COUNTA(Sheet1!$H:$H))
  ```
- Insert your dropdown validation list and reference the named range

  ```
  =DropList
  ```
- Confirm

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(D2,A1:A7,0),2)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(D2,A1:A7,0)+COUNTIF(A1:A7,D2)-1,2))
```

This should work, assuming the data is sorted by name. `ADDRESS(MATCH(D1,A1:A7,0)+1,2)`, add that to the number of rows used in heading, in this case 1, this should return the address of the first cell of the data, column `'2'` refers to the column in which data is and it should return `"$B$2"`, then in the second part of the formula we calculate the number of `'A'` in the data using `COUNTIF` and add it to the first cell of the variable, similar to the 1st formula we give column as 2.
Then we use Indirect function to convert the strings to address which the data validation can use. And i guess you already know how to use Lists in data validation.

Alternatively, you can keep the address part in one cell, either hide the column or colour text white and protect the cell, and the refer as indirect from the Lists in data validation.

Comment: Good you noticed, the mock-up data is sorted. A helper column wouldn't be needed, but a volatile function such as `INDIRECT` would recalculate even in a named range, on every recalculation, upon opening and saving the workbook.